# Hash Table Replace is replacing all keys content instead of only one

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I am trying to create a function that reads a .csv file and store and sort information into hash tables to later be accessed.

I wish to use the function replace from glib hash tables to change the content in the position with X key when that key already has a value stored inside. But it is instead changing the content of all positions when i just want one.

Am i using the wrong function for this or i have to approach this in a different way?

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../includes/estatisticas.h"
#include "../includes/Drivers.h"

#define MAX_LENGHT_RIDES 2000000

GHashTable** rides(GHashTable** arr_drivers){
    FILE* rides_files = fopen("../Entrada/rides.csv", "r");
    GHashTable* h_preco_medio = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, NULL, NULL);
    GHashTable* h_number_city = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, NULL, NULL);
    char* ptr;
    char* city = malloc(MAX_LENGHT_RIDES);
    char* str = calloc(1, MAX_LENGHT_RIDES);
    
    fgets(str, MAX_LENGHT_RIDES, rides_files);
    while (fgets(str, MAX_LENGHT_RIDES, rides_files)){
        char* line = str;
        char* id = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        char* date = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        char* driver = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        char* user = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        city = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        double distance = strtod(strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n")), &ptr);
        char* score_user = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        char* score_driver = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n"));
        double tip = strtod(strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n\r")), &ptr);
        char* comment = strdup(strsep(&line, ";\n\r"));

        char* car_class = (char*) g_hash_table_lookup(arr_drivers[0], driver);

        double* preco;
        preco[0] = calc_preco(distance, car_class);
        if(!g_hash_table_lookup(h_preco_medio, city)){
            g_hash_table_insert(h_preco_medio, city, preco);
            int* city_counter;
            city_counter[0] = 1;
            g_hash_table_insert(h_number_city, city, city_counter);
        }
        else{
            double* novo_preco;
            novo_preco[0] = ((double*) g_hash_table_lookup(h_preco_medio, city))[0] + preco[0];
            g_hash_table_replace(h_preco_medio, city, novo_preco);  
            int* new_city_counter;
            new_city_counter[0] = ((int*) g_hash_table_lookup(h_number_city, city))[0] + 1;
            g_hash_table_replace(h_number_city, city, new_city_counter); 
            printf("%d\n", ((int*) g_hash_table_lookup(h_number_city, "Faro"))[0]);
        }
    }

    GHashTable** arr = calloc(5, sizeof(GHashTable*));
    arr[0] = h_preco_medio;
    arr[1] = h_number_city;

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: PSA: `strsep()` can return `NULL`. If you `strdup()` that, bad times. You may want to use a proper CSV parsing library rather than bang your own together.

Comment: You don't need these `strdup` calls.  Don't copy data that you don't need to copy.  And if you keep the `strdup` calls, you ought to add a `free` for each.  `strtod(strdup(...))` is a guaranteed memory leak.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think those will be required unless `line` is itself duplicated. Additionally, CSV often requires decoding, so using slices of the `line` data is not always practical.

Comment: `double* preco; preco[0] = ... ` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially many other issues, but you have undefined behavior at:

```
 double* preco;
 preco[0] = ...
```

After the invalid memory access, the behavior is undefined and anything can happen.  The classical example is that demons may fly out of your nostrils, but very few implementations actually produce that result.

Note that most of the `strdup` calls in your code don't appear to be necessary.  Since `city` is the key in your hash table, that is (probbably) the only value that needs to be duplicated.  (I haven't looked too closely at your code; if it goes in the hash table it needs to be copied out of `line`.  If it doesn't, it (almost certainly) doesn't need to be copied.) In any case, you certainly don't need `strtod(strdup(...))`, which copies the string, computes its value, and then immediatly leaks the copy.  Keep the data in `line` only until it is going into the hash table, and only `strdup` the portions that are going in the hash table.  And make sure everything you copy eventually gets `free`d.  It can be tempting to allow all the frees to happen when the process closes, but adding in the explicit frees will be a good bookkeeping exercise that may expose issues in your code (and you understanding).